# Including nib file for custom UIView in CellForRowAt producing jerk while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, scroll, nib

I have a UITableView and I am including a nib file of my custom UIView in a "CellForRowAt" delegate function of tableView which is producing jerk while scrolling. For Example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
       "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
       let customView: CustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: 
       self, options: nil)![0] as! customView
       cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView)
       return cell
}
```

How can I fix the scrolling and what is the issue in my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView)
```

This is not how you create cell and reuse in your `cellForRow`, you are basically create new view and add it everytime your cell scroll (keep making duplicated), thus make it jerking, you have to create your cell nib with that view, and register your nib file in `viewDidLoad` like:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

and in `cellForRow` just dequeue like normal:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

If you have many different kind of cell, make multiple cells class, not make new view and add to current cell

Comment: No, you are taking it wrong. I am not creating the nib for tableViewCell. customView is the view which i am placing in the cell.

let customView: CustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! customView    //this is my customView............
cell.customViewPlacement.addSubview(customView) // this is where I am placing my customView.

Comment: Thats where you are wrong, you are suppose to create the nib that contains cell with that view you are saying, not separate them, if you cant do that for whatever reason, add the view to the cell in the `CustomCell` class's `awakeFromNib`, not from `cellForRow`